# Do we have Test explorer in VS code?

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumber, visual-studio-code, test-explorer

I'm working in Protractor cucumber framework in node js.

Do we have test explorer or any plugin which lists all the TCs in the feature files of the project? So that we can execute the test directly from  the test exlporer?

We have test explorer in Visual studio. Same way is it available in VS code?

Comment: anything found for you question ? i am struggling for the same